# Developing a Complex Number

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Develop $3^i$.

I don't understand how to even begin approaching this problem.

The best way to for me to understand this, I think, would be to see a complete solution or a kick starter at least.

Comment: Let $3^i = x$.  Take logs, and then can you see what x could be?  If that does not help, what do you know about complex exponentiation so far?

Answer (score 2):

We can consider the principal branch in $\mathbb{C}-\{(-\infty,0]\}$, and in this branch we can write $z^\alpha=e^{\alpha\rm{ \ log \ }z}$ for all $z,\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

Doing $z=3$ and $\alpha = i$ we get the following

$3^i=e^{i\rm{ \ log \ } 3}=\rm{cos}(\rm{log \ }3) +i\cdot\rm{sin}(\rm{log \ }3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Euler's formula?  $e^{\theta i} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$  (This will be helpful to memorize, fyi.)

Also, a helpful simplification is $a^b = e^{(\ln a)b}$.

With those two formulas:
$$3^i = e^{i\ln 3}$$
Thus, for Euler's formula, $\theta=\ln 3$.  I think you can take it from here..